# Why can't you directly update the result of an Active Record find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Updating the result of an Active Record `find` works as expected when you assign it to a variable:

```rb
user = User.find(1790)
user.archived          # => true
user.archived = false
user.save              # => true
user.archived          # => false
```

Why can't you update the result of the `find` directly?

```rb
User.find(1790).archived          # => true
User.find(1790).archived = false
User.find(1790).save              # => true
User.find(1790).archived          # => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you do `find`, you're getting a new instance of `User` based on the current values in the `users` table. So, when you `User.find(1790).save`, the `User` instance no longer has `.archived = false` because you just retrieved the record from the database (by doing `User.find`) which has `archived = true`.

Try:

```
User.find(1790).archived          # => true
User.find(1790).archived = false
User.find(1790).changed?          # => false
User.find(1790).save              # => true
User.find(1790).archived          # => true
```

But, see what happens when you do:

```
User.find(1790).archived                # => true
User.find(1790).update(archived: false) # => true
User.find(1790).archived                # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.find(1790)` - As its clear from method name that it `finds record matching given conditions`. This runs a query and gets the record each and every time. Hence setting values in this statement does not reflect as it is `set locally` for just that statement.
When you again call `User.find(1790).save` the previously set value is not retained and the find query is executed again.

Whereas when you assign the result to a variable, you can modify the variable value and save it, which then updates the active record.